# Getting a Value from an Input Box and Assign it in a Variable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Hi I'm just new to Javascript and I am trying to assign a value to a variable coming from the input box then access that variable in a loop. I have tried using document.getElementbyID('inputboxID').value; and document.getElementbyName('inputboxName').value; but it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
var count = 0;

$(function(){
$('p#add_field').click(function() {
var num = document.getElementById('enfonum').value;
while (count < num) {
count +=1;
$('#container').append( 
'<strong>Enforcer #'+count+'</strong><br/>'
+'<input id="field_  '+count+'"name="field[]'+'"type="text"/><br/>');
}
});
});
}
</script>
```

Here's the code for the input box:

```
<input type="text" id="enfonum" name="enfotxt"/>
```

and here's the code for the link that will trigger the script to be executed:

```
<p id="add_field">< a href="#"><span>&raquo; Add Enforcer</span></a></p>
```

Comment: change GetElementById to getElementById

Comment: I've already used lowercase g but still it doesn't work. :( @vvtx

Comment: try to debug your code , first return the value of num to the console and see if the value is coming or not and then go for your jquery

Comment: var num = document.getElementById('enfonum').value; should be inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get value of `enfonum` input at run-time, not storing it at `num` var during initial page loading.
Here is the working sample with correct code:

```js
var count = 0;
    var num = document.getElementById('enfonum');

    $('p#add_field').click(function () {

      while (count < num.value) {
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append('<p><strong>Enforcer #' + count + '</strong><br/>'
        + '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="field[]' + ' "type="text"/><br/></p>');
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><input type="text" id="enfonum" name="enfotxt" /></p>
<p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>&raquo; Add Enforcer</span></a></p>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi SIr! Thank you sooooo much! It works! It's such a great help! :) I've already voted your answer up but my reputation isn't enough. :(

Comment: you are welcome. without enough reputation, still you can choose this as Accepted Answer! ;D to support good coders (select the tick mark beside the answer)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working, is simply that `document.GetElementById` does not exists, the correct syntax is `document.getElementById`.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfhfsk5u/1/) with an example.

Good luck and good continuation,

Cheers !

Comment: Sir thank you for the response. I've already changed it but still it doesn't get any value. @Elhebert

Comment: I didn't payed attention, but you are using jQuery in your code, you could then simply do `$('#enfonum').val()` (see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk0x4a6z/)).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **extra** `}` in the code, it will give you syntax error.
Tried it afterwards,the code works.
Syntax errors can break your javascript, it is wise to use plugins like *firebug* for firefox to fish out javascript errors.

Let me know if it works.